# jQuery on Crispy Forms input fields not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

```html
<div id="div_id_code" class="form-group"> <label for="id_code" class="control-label col-lg-2 requiredField">
                Code<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="controls "> <input type="text" name="code" maxlength="50" class="textinput textInput form-control" required id="id_code" /> </div> </div> <div id="div_id_description" class="form-group"> <label for="id_description" class="control-label col-lg-2 requiredField">
                Description<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="controls "> <input type="text" name="description" maxlength="100" class="textinput textInput form-control" required id="id_description" /> </div> </div> <div id="div_id_qty" class="form-group"> <label for="id_qty" class="control-label col-lg-2 requiredField">
                Qty<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="controls "> <input type="number" name="qty" value="0" css-id="qty_id" class="numberinput form-control" required id="id_qty" /> </div> </div> <div id="div_id_price" class="form-group"> <label for="id_price" class="control-label col-lg-2 requiredField">
                Price<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="controls "> <input type="number" name="price" value="0" step="0.01" css-id="price_id" class="numberinput form-control" required id="id_price" /> </div> </div> <div id="div_id_total" class="form-group"> <label for="id_total" class="control-label col-lg-2 requiredField">
                Total<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="controls "> <input type="number" name="total" value="0" step="0.01" css-id="total_id" class="numberinput form-control" required id="id_total" /> </div>
```

I'm using Django Crispy Forms. When I use `qty_id` and `price_id` with jQuery for some calculations, it doesn't work.
I want to add their values multiplied by the value field.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#qty_id').on('change', function () {
        $('#total_id').val($('#qty_id').val() * $('#price_id').val());
    });
    $('#price_id').on('change', function () {
        $('#total_id').val($('#qty_id').val() * $('#price_id').val());
    });
};
```

**forms.py**:

```
class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-2'
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-inline'

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
                Field('code',),
                'description',
                Field('qty', id="qty_id"),
                Field('price', id="price_id"),
                Field('total', id="total_id"),
                'employee',
            )

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('code', 'description', 'qty', 'price', 'total', 'employee',)
```

Comment: Show the generated html.

Comment: @aaron see above i've added the generated html

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out i missed the bracket in the jQuery ready method it's all good now working as expected